# KVM VM not working

Tags: permissions, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Im getting this error when creating a VM in virt manager using KVM.  (Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2015-12-02T23:01:04.368439Z qemu-system-i386: -drive file=/home/christian/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0,format=raw: Could not open '/home/christian/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso': Permission denied) I tried doing sudo virt-manager and still does not work.

Comment: What are the permissions on that file, the Downloads directory, and your home directory?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the VM libvirt/KVM will want to change the group and owner of the iso file, and it needs to able to do so. Example from my iso directory:

```
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   722468864 Oct  5 22:50 ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug  599785472 Feb  4  2015 ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso
-rw-r--r--  1 doug         doug  623902720 May 23  2015 ubuntu-14.04.2-server-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 doug         doug 1054867456 Oct 16 14:12 ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1149714432 Apr  3  2015 vivid-desktop-amd64-20150403.iso
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 libvirt-qemu kvm  1267597312 Sep 21 09:13 wily-desktop-amd64-20150921.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1267597312 Sep 23 16:45 wily-desktop-amd64-20150922.1.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 libvirt-qemu kvm  1267597312 Sep 22 08:08 wily-desktop-amd64-20150922.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1268842496 Sep 26 18:36 wily-desktop-amd64-20150924.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 libvirt-qemu kvm  1265106944 Oct  5 17:25 wily-desktop-amd64-20151005.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1265106944 Oct 16 10:34 wily-desktop-amd64-20151016.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1265106944 Oct 16 02:40 wily-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 libvirt-qemu kvm   654311424 Jul  7 07:13 wily-server-20150707-amd64.iso
-rw-r--r--  1 doug         doug  715128832 Sep 26 17:23 wily-server-amd64-20150924.iso
-rw-r--r--  1 doug         doug  715128832 Sep 25 22:46 wily-server-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 libvirt-qemu kvm  1306066944 Nov  7 21:15 xenial-desktop-amd64-2015-11-07.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1306066944 Nov 12 23:17 xenial-desktop-amd64-2015-11-12.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1306066944 Nov 13 22:04 xenial-desktop-amd64-2015-11-13.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug 1306066944 Nov 12 23:59 xenial-desktop-amd64.iso
-rw-rwxr--  1 doug         doug  725614592 Oct 30 14:43 xenial-server-amd64-20151030.iso
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 doug         doug  725614592 Oct 30 14:36 xenial-server-amd64.iso
```

So, I would suggest to set the file permissions for your iso file the same as I have mine set.

Disclaimer: I don't actually use virt manager, I use virt-install, so things might be a little different for you.

Comment: How do I do that? @Doug Smythies

Comment: Add the output for `ls -l /home/christian/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso` to your question, so that a reply can be made specific to your situation. And @psusi has a good point, what are the parent permissions?